# How to add a column to this matrix?

Tags: nicematrix

I want to add a column to this matrix like this
[image]

My code

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
        \NiceMatrixOptions
        {
            delimiters/max-width,
            light-syntax,
            last-col, code-for-last-col = \color{blue}\scriptstyle,
        }
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            1 -2 4 3  ;
            3 -5 -1 -2  ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 4 -7 1 { L_2 \gets L_1-L_2
            } ;
            0 11 -8 14 { L_3 \gets 3L_1-L_3
            } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 44 -77 11 { L_2 \gets 4L_2
            } ;
            0 44 -32 56 { L_3 \gets 4L_3
            } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 44 -77 11 { L_2 \gets 4L_2
            } ;
            0 0 -45 -45 { L_3 \gets L_2 - L_3
            } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
    \end{NiceMatrixBlock}
    
    $\begin{NiceArray}{ccc@{}w{c}{5mm}@{}ccc}
        & & && 1 & 2 & -3\\
        & & && 0 & 44 & -77 \\
        & & && 0 & 0 & -45 \\
        \CodeAfter
        \NewDocumentCommand{\MyDraw}{}{\tikz \draw [blue] (2-|1) -| (3-|2) -| (4-|3) ;}
        \SubMatrix({1-5}{3-7})[code = \MyDraw]
    \end{NiceArray}$
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only have to draw the line you want in the `\CodeAfter` of the last `{pNiceArray}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
        \NiceMatrixOptions
        {
            delimiters/max-width,
            light-syntax,
            last-col, code-for-last-col = \color{blue}\scriptstyle,
        }
        \setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            1 -2 4 3  ;
            3 -5 -1 -2  ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 4 -7 1 { L_2 \gets L_1-L_2
            } ;
            0 11 -8 14 { L_3 \gets 3L_1-L_3
            } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 44 -77 11 { L_2 \gets 4L_2
            } ;
            0 44 -32 56 { L_3 \gets 4L_3
            } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 44 -77 11 { L_2 \gets 4L_2
            } ;
            0 0 -45 -45 { L_3 \gets L_2 - L_3
            } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
             1   2   -3    4 {} ;
             0  44  -77   11 ;
             0   0  -45  -45 ;
        \CodeAfter
          \tikz \draw [blue] ([xshift=1mm]2-|1) -| (3-|2) -| (4-|3) ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 3):

It seems like overkill to create a `pNicearray` for the final array. Here, then, is a solution that employs an "ordinary" `array` instead.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1mm}

\newlength\mylen
\settowidth\mylen{$-44$}
\addtolength\mylen{0.3pt} % column width in 'array' env.
\newcommand\0{\multicolumn{1}{r|}{0}} % handy shortcut command
        
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceMatrixBlock}[auto-columns-width]
        \NiceMatrixOptions
        { delimiters/max-width,
          light-syntax,
          last-col, 
          code-for-last-col = \color{blue}\scriptstyle,
        }
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            1 -2 4 3  ;
            3 -5 -1 -2  ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 4 -7 1 { L_2 \gets L_1-L_2 } ;
            0 11 -8 14 { L_3 \gets 3L_1-L_3 } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 44 -77 11 { L_2 \gets 4L_2 } ;
            0 44 -32 56 { L_3 \gets 4L_3 } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$
        
        \smallskip
        $\begin{pNiceArray}{rrr|r}
            1 2 -3 4 {} ;
            0 44 -77 11 { L_2 \gets 4L_2 } ;
            0 0 -45 -45 { L_3 \gets L_2 - L_3 } ;
        \end{pNiceArray}$     
\end{NiceMatrixBlock}
    
\smallskip
$\left( \begin{array}{@{} *{3}{wr{\mylen}}| wr{\mylen} @{}}
         1 &  2 &  -3 &   4 \\ \cline{1-1}
        \0 & 44 & -77 &  11 \\ \cline{2-2}
         0 & \0 & -45 & -45 
\end{array} \right)$

\end{document}
```